# Editing the Cached Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

In the documentation there is a section Cloth Simulations --> Settings --> Cache --> Editing the Cached Simulation.

I'm trying to edit the cached simulation but not finding the "Bake Editing" button or the "Rebake from next Frame" button.

Do these functions still exists?